# Managing multi-level dicts through multiple levels of tkinter input widgets

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

Been struggling with this for a few days, so hopefully can get some help.
Have reviewed many explanations here for tkinter input, including several by Bryan Oakley, but I do not find this scenario outlined.

Problem : I am trying to use tkinter widgets to collect and store several user inputs for later use. There are ~50 user inputs needed. My idea was to store them in a dict and organize the dict into multiple levels. There are various types of widgets that correspond to the type of inputs requested, so using Entry, lists of Radiobuttons, lists of Checkboxes, etc.

The idea was to construct the user interface in a class Application, provide the default dict to the class instance, and then have each widget have access to a specific key/value or values in the dict to update.

I cannot figure out how to update/modify specific values in a multi-level dict from a widget that is also 2 or 3 levels deep into the widget layout structure.

I am not restricted to the idea of a dict ... just works for organizing the info. If json or some other structure makes this easier, I can adapt.

Current code example ...

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

# ...   -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
# ...   default dict ... goal is to allow user to change these values
# ...   using tkinter input widgets (Entry, Radiobutton, Checkbox, ...)
# ...   and store updated dictionary in external text file
# ...   there are ~50 different values that need to be managed
# ...   -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

default_config = {
    'general': {
        'logging_level': 'DEBUG'},
    'functions': {
        'input': {
            'input_dir': '../data/raw/',
            'input_file': 'my_input.csv'},
        'output': {
            'output_file': 'my_output.csv'},
    }
}


class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, this_config, **kwargs):

        self.this_config = this_config

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, self.root)
        self.grid()

        # manage different sets of inputs in different Frame columns
        self.file_mgmt_column = tk.Frame(self)
        self.file_mgmt_column.grid()

        # one of several user input widgets in this frame
        self.input_dir = InputDir(self.file_mgmt_column, **self.this_config)
        self.input_dir.grid()

# ... exit from all
        self.quit = Quit(self.root)
        self.quit.grid()

# ...   -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
# ...   quit button
# ...   -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-


class Quit(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.quit = tk.Button(parent, text="Quit", command=parent.quit)
        self.quit.grid()

# ...   -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
# ...   input directory selection
# ...   -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-


class InputDir(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, **lx_config):
        
        # ... this version receives the dict as **kwargs, but also desire to supply widget formatting
        # ... definition through **kwargs, to have common formatting across all widgets

        self.current_config = lx_config

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.input_dir_label = tk.Label(self, text = 'input directory (raw):')
        self.input_dir_label.grid()

        # this is hard-coding in the specific dictionary keys to the display the current text value
        # need a way to define this set of keys at method call from Application __init__ level
        self.input_dir = tk.StringVar()
        self.input_dir.set(self.current_config['functions']['input']['input_dir'])

        self.input_dir_entry = tk.Entry(self, width = 75,
                                        textvariable=self.input_dir)
        self.input_dir_entry.grid()

        self.select_button = tk.Button(self,
                                       text = 'Select directory',
                                       command = self.select_folder)
        self.select_button.grid()

        self.select_button.bind('<1>',
                                lambda event, obj=self.input_dir,
                                       val=self.current_config['functions']['input']['input_dir']:
                                           self.select_folder(event, obj, val))

    def select_folder(self, event, obj, val):

        self.input_dir = filedialog.askdirectory()
        obj.set(self.input_dir)

        # ... ??????????????????????
        # ... how to make a change to default config['functions']['input']['input_dir']
        # ... in this case, it is text field (file directory)
        # ... for other inputs, may be a list of multiple text values, e.g.,
        # ... a list of files
        # ... ??????????????????????

        val = self.input_dir # does not change value in primary dict

        print('event : %s' % event)
        print('selected folder() ... %s' % self.input_dir)
        print('updated value ... %s' % str(val))


# ...   -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
# ...   main app
# ...   -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = Application(default_config)
    app.mainloop()

    print(default_config['functions']['input'])
    
    # ... after user inputs have been received ... then take next steps with updated dict ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments:

1. Separate your widget config from the config dictionary you are trying to edit.  Mixing the two will only cause pain.
2. For consistent widget appearance, use `ttk` (`from tkinter import ttk`) and styles.
3. A typical grid layout is to have the label in the left column and the value to edit in the right.  Your use of just `.grid()` puts each item on a separate row (see my example for a way to do just this).

And a modified example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk

# ...   -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
# ...   default dict ... goal is to allow user to change these values
# ...   using tkinter input widgets (Entry, Radiobutton, Checkbox, ...)
# ...   and store updated dictionary in external text file
# ...   there are ~50 different values that need to be managed
# ...   -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

default_config = {
    'general': {
        'logging_level': 'DEBUG'},
    'functions': {
        'input': {
            'input_dir': '../data/raw/',
            'input_file': 'my_input.csv'},
        'output': {
            'output_file': 'my_output.csv'},
    },
    'example': {
        'some_value': 'anything',
        'some_bool': True,
    },
}


class ConfEntry:
    """Like tk.Entry, but value is auto-stored to a dictionary element"""
    def __init__(self, parent, label, config, item, **kwargs):
        self.config = config
        self.item = item
        self.label = tk.Label(parent, text=label, justify=tk.LEFT)
        self.var = tk.StringVar(parent, value=self.config[self.item])
        self.entry = tk.Entry(parent, textvariable=self.var)
        self.var.trace_add('write', self.update_value)

    def grid(self, row, column=0):
        self.label.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky='w')
        self.entry.grid(row=row, column=column+1)

    def update_value(self, *_ignored):
        self.config[self.item] = self.var.get()


class ConfCheckbutton:
    """Like tk.Checkbutton, but value is auto-stored to a dictionary element"""
    def __init__(self, parent, label, config, item, **kwargs):
        self.config = config
        self.item = item
        self.label = tk.Label(parent, text=label, justify=tk.LEFT)
        self.var = tk.BooleanVar(parent, value=self.config[self.item])
        self.cb = tk.Checkbutton(parent, variable=self.var)
        self.var.trace_add('write', self.update_value)

    def grid(self, row, column=0):
        self.label.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky='w')
        self.cb.grid(row=row, column=column+1)

    def update_value(self, *_ignored):
        self.config[self.item] = self.var.get()


class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, this_config, **kwargs):
        self.this_config = this_config

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, self.root)
        self.grid()

        # manage different sets of inputs in different Frame columns
        self.file_mgmt_column = tk.Frame(self)
        self.file_mgmt_column.grid()

        # one of several user input widgets in this frame
        self.input_dir = InputDir(self.file_mgmt_column, **self.this_config)
        self.input_dir.grid()

        ttk.Separator(self).grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=100, padx=4, sticky='ns')
        self.example_column = tk.Frame(self)
        self.example_column.grid(row=0, column=2)

        lbl = tk.Label(self.example_column, text='Examples in this Column', justify=tk.CENTER)
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='ew')
        self.example_value = ConfEntry(self.example_column, 'Example', self.this_config['example'], 'some_value')
        self.example_value.grid(row=1)

        self.example_bool = ConfCheckbutton(self.example_column, 'Example Bool', self.this_config['example'], 'some_bool')
        self.example_bool.grid(row=2)

        # ... exit from all
        self.quit = Quit(self.root)
        self.quit.grid()


# ...   -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
# ...   quit button
# ...   -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-


class Quit(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.quit = tk.Button(parent, text="Quit", command=parent.quit)
        self.quit.grid()


# ...   -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
# ...   input directory selection
# ...   -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-


class InputDir(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, **lx_config):
        # ... this version receives the dict as **kwargs, but also desire to supply widget formatting
        # ... definition through **kwargs, to have common formatting across all widgets

        self.current_config = lx_config

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.input_dir_label = tk.Label(self, text='input directory (raw):')
        self.input_dir_label.grid()

        # this is hard-coding in the specific dictionary keys to the display the current text value
        # need a way to define this set of keys at method call from Application __init__ level
        self.input_dir = tk.StringVar()
        self.input_dir.set(self.current_config['functions']['input']['input_dir'])

        self.input_dir_entry = tk.Entry(self, width=75,
                                        textvariable=self.input_dir)
        self.input_dir_entry.grid()

        self.select_button = tk.Button(self,
                                       text='Select directory',
                                       command=self.select_folder)
        self.select_button.grid()

        self.select_button.bind('<1>',
                                lambda event, obj=self.input_dir,
                                       val=self.current_config['functions']['input']['input_dir']:
                                self.select_folder(event, obj, val))

    def select_folder(self, event, obj, val):
        self.input_dir = filedialog.askdirectory()
        obj.set(self.input_dir)

        # ... ??????????????????????
        # ... how to make a change to default config['functions']['input']['input_dir']
        # ... in this case, it is text field (file directory)
        # ... for other inputs, may be a list of multiple text values, e.g.,
        # ... a list of files
        # ... ??????????????????????

        val = self.input_dir  # does not change value in primary dict

        print('event : %s' % event)
        print('selected folder() ... %s' % self.input_dir)
        print('updated value ... %s' % str(val))


# ...   -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
# ...   main app
# ...   -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application(default_config)
    app.mainloop()

    print(default_config['functions']['input'])
    print(default_config['example'])

    # ... after user inputs have been received ... then take next steps with updated dict ...
```

Comment: I want to thank you very much for this answer. This gives me a different (and much improved) perspective on how to construct these classes to work together. And it works for me. I appreciate that your response/solution retained the basic structure of what I am trying to achieve, and provides me the framework in which to accomplish that.